# Run website on iPhone and Blackberry

Tags: iphone, blackberry

My friend has a website for buying and selling products and the website is running fine, but he wants to be able to access his website from Blackberry and iPhone. He is not a mobile application developer. If anyone knows the easiest and fastest way to do that, we would appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, there will be a couple things you need to do.  First, since the screen size is different, you will probably want to target each platform independently.  Second, you will need to format your site to work in the small-screen format.  Third, you will want to consider what to do on rotation of the screens.  Finally, you want to watch to be sure you don't include any content that cannot be rendered on the mobile browser (Flash, etc.)

How granular you get with this depends on how good you want the experience to be.  For example, you could format your controls, etc. to be more like the native controls of the devices you are targeting.  There are specific looks to iPhone buttons, text boxes, etc. that you can mimic for the iPhone-specific site.  The same is true for Blackberry.  However, it would be simplest if you just targeted the screen size and rotation issues first and worked up from there.

Here is a tutorial for how to do this when targetting a Blackberry device:

http://www.phpexpertsforum.com/how-to-develop-a-blackberry-browser-compatible-website-t569.html

Here is a tutorial on how to target an iPhone device:

http://www.engageinteractive.co.uk/blog/2008/06/19/tutorial-building-a-website-for-the-iphone/

Answer (score 1):

It isn't super difficult; at the server, if you detect that the user agent string is a phone, you serve a version of the website that is optimized for mobile viewing (you should also provide an escape hatch to allow the user to switch between the full version of the website and the mobile version of the website).

Mobile optimized means that your CSS is designed for the size of a phone screen, you have buttons that are larger than normal to make it easy for users to press, and you keep things a little more minimal to avoid over-cluttering what is otherwise a small screen. However, it is still just regular HTML, CSS, JS.

Answer (score 0):

I see a couple options:

- Live with the site as-is. The iPhone has a Webkit browser and so renders modern sites quite well. Is it a great experience? Not necessarily so, but it will still work. I don't know which Blackberry your friend has, and that does make a difference. Newer models have a decent Webkit browser which will do fine; others have older browsers, that, frankly, just suck.
- Build a new front-end with "mobile" in mind. All your back-end code should be the same, but when thinking "mobile" (especially for older browsers), you should think about making the site as lean and simple as possible. It is still all HTML/CSS/Javascript, so you don't need to know anything about mobile app development, just use the same web skills to build a simpler site.

  - If you are always going to target a modern webkit browser like on iPhone or Android and newer Blackberries, you can use lots of mobile frameworks to help you get started. A lot look quite a lot like the native widgets, though the feel isn't always quite there.